# Diagram in TikZ gives compiling error

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

Here's my code which is working on the landscape mode:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[rectangle, draw, thick,minimum width=5cm,minimum height=2.20cm] at (0,1){

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[input]    (Method1)     at (0,1) {Method1};
\end{tikzpicture}
        };

\node[rectangle, draw, thick,minimum width=5cm,minimum height=2.20cm] at (8,1){
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[input]    (Procedure1)     at (6,1) {Procedure1};
\end{tikzpicture}
%\draw [->] (0,-1) -- (8,-1);
        }; 
\node[rectangle, draw, thick,minimum width=5cm,minimum height=2.20cm] at (0,6){
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[input]    (Procedure2)     at (0,6) {Procedure2};
\end{tikzpicture}           
        };
\node[rectangle, draw, thick,minimum width=8cm,minimum height=2.20cm] at (10,6){
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[input]    (Procedure3)     at (6,6) {Procedure3};
\end{tikzpicture}               
        };           
\node[rectangle, draw, thick,minimum width=5cm,minimum height=2.20cm] at (0,11){
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[input]    (Method2)     at (0,11) {Method2};
\end{tikzpicture}
            };
\node[rectangle, draw, thick,minimum width=5cm,minimum height=2.20cm] at (6,11){
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[input]    (ProcedureA)     at (6,11) {ProcedureA};
\end{tikzpicture}               
        };
\node[rectangle, draw, thick,minimum width=5cm,minimum height=2.20cm] at (12,11){
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[input]    (ProcedureB)     at (12,11) {ProcedureB};
\end{tikzpicture}               
        };
\node[rectangle, draw, thick,minimum width=5cm,minimum height=2.20cm] at (18,11){
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[input]    (ProcedureC)     at (18,11) {ProcedureC};
\end{tikzpicture}                   
        };
\node[rectangle, draw, thick,minimum width=4cm,minimum height=2.20cm] at (0,-4){
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[input]    (Method3)     at (0,-4) {Method3};
\end{tikzpicture}
};      
\node[rectangle, draw, thick,minimum width=4cm,minimum height=2.20cm] at (10,-4){
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[input]    (ProcedureAB)     at (10,-4) {ProcedureAB};
%\draw [->] (10,-4)
\end{tikzpicture}
        };
\node[rectangle, draw, thick,minimum width=4cm,minimum height=2.20cm] at (19.10,-4){
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[input]  (ProcedureABC)      at (19.50,-4) {ProcedureABC}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
        };
\draw[>=latex,->] (2.65,1)--(3.90,1);
\draw[>=latex,->] (2.65,6)--(3.90,6);
\draw[>=latex,->] (2.10,-4)--(4,-4);
\draw[>=latex,->] (2.70,11)--(3.10,11);
\draw[>=latex,->] (9,11)--(9.40,11);
\draw[>=latex,->] (14.70,11)--(15.10,11);
\draw[>=latex,->] (.15,4.35)--(.15,2.70);
\draw[>=latex,->] (.15,-.60)--(.15,-2.35);
\draw[>=latex,->] (.15,9.30)--(.15,7.70);
\draw[>=latex,->] (16.10,-4)--(17,-4);               
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

However, I have many bug-some error that I could not solve.

1) Package [`pgfkeys`][1] Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/input' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

2)
Missing `\endcsname` inserted.

3) 
Package [`TikZ`][2] Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?

Can you help me debugging this?

Comment: (1) It's not recommended to nest TikZ pictures within nodes or even within TikZ pictures.  There's probably a better way to do that.

Comment: (2) Please make this compilable by including the preamble.  In particular, you have keywords passed to nodes, but they are not standard keywords.

Comment: I have in the preamable \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

Comment: There's got to be something more.  For example you're passing nodes the keyword `input`.  What's that supposed to be?

Comment: With a null definition for the keyword `input` and the addition of `\begin{figure}`, this compiles fine for me.

Comment: You said this worked in a different context.  Perhaps you also want to post what did work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Your code can be cleaned up quite a bit and made easier to read

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{input/.style={}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[my node/.style={rectangle, draw, thick,minimum width=#1,minimum height=2.20cm,outer sep=4pt},
                    >=latex]

\node[my node=5cm] (M1) at (0,1){ Method1 };
\node[my node=5cm] (P1) at (8,1){ Procedure1 };
\node[my node=5cm] (P2) at (0,6){ Procedure2};
\node[my node=8cm] (P3) at (10,6){ Procedure3};
\node[my node=5cm] (M2) at (0,11){Method2};
\node[my node=5cm] (PA) at (6,11){ProcedureA};
\node[my node=5cm] (PB) at (12,11){ProcedureB};
\node[my node=5cm] (PC) at (18,11){ProcedureC};
\node[my node=4cm] (M3) at (0,-4){Method3};
\node[my node=4cm] (PAB) at (10,-4){ProcedureAB};
\node[my node=4cm] (PABC) at (19.10,-4){ProcedureABC};


\foreach \myA/\myB in {M1/P1,
                       P2/P3,
                       M3/PAB,
                       M2/PA,
                       PA/PB,
                       PB/PC,
                       M2/P2,
                       P2/M1,
                       M1/M3,
                       PAB/PABC%%
                       }
{
  \draw[->,line width=2pt,opacity=0.20] (\myA) -- (\myB);
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You could probably even use the `positioning` library to make this even easier.

In this next example, I using the `positioning` library to finesse the alignment of the different boxes.  The key word `on grid` makes sure that the nodes are aligned on their center.  To enable the text to wrap in each node, I use the keyword `text width=<dimension>` and set the alignment to *centering* via `align=center`.

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{input/.style={}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[my node/.style={on grid,rectangle, draw, thick,minimum width=#1,minimum height=2.20cm,outer sep=4pt},
                    node distance=4cm and 8cm,
                    >=latex]

\node[my node=5cm] (M1)                {Qualitative};
\node[my node=5cm,right=of M1]  (P1)   {Contexts examination of concordance lines};
\node[my node=5cm,above=of M1]  (P2)   {Concordancing};
\node[my node=8cm,right=of P2,text width=7.75cm,align=center]  (P3)   {Make a conconrdance of Metaphor Keywords in the whole corpus};
\node[my node=5cm,above=of P2]  (M2)   {Qualitative};
\node[my node=5cm,right=of M2]  (PA)   {Close Reading of 10\% corpus};
\node[my node=5cm,right=of PA]  (PB)   {Metaphor Identification};
\node[my node=5cm,right=of PB]  (PC)   {Forming Metaphor Keywords};
\node[my node=4cm,below=of M1]  (M3)   {Quantitative};
\node[my node=4cm,right=of M3,text width=3.75cm,align=center]  (PAB)  {Reporting descriptive statistics (percentages, distributions, etc)};
\node[my node=4cm,right=of PAB] (PABC) {Hypothesis testing};

\foreach \myA/\myB in {M1/P1,
                       P2/P3,
                       M3/PAB,
                       M2/PA,
                       PA/PB,
                       PB/PC,
                       M2/P2,
                       P2/M1,
                       M1/M3,
                       PAB/PABC%%
                       }
{
  \draw[->,line width=1pt] (\myA) -- (\myB);
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Only thing is that I don't know what `input` is supposed to mean.  So, its effect is completely missing from my solution.